# Dataflow(TPL) - exception handling issue?

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong or it's an issue with Dataflow but I can't work out when [Receive()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160429(v=vs.110).aspx) throws exception.
When I run this test:

```
public class AsyncProblem
{
    [Fact]
    public void AsyncVsAwaiterProblem()
    {
        var max = 1000;
        var noOfExceptions = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Await().Wait();
            }
            catch
            {
                noOfExceptions++;
            }
        }
        Assert.Equal(max,noOfExceptions);
    }

    public async Task Await()
    {
        bool firstPassed = false;
        var divideBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>((x) =>
        {
            if (firstPassed)
                throw new ArgumentException("error");
            firstPassed = true;
            return 0;
        });
        divideBlock.Post(2);
        divideBlock.Post(3); // this should cause failure;
        divideBlock.Complete();

        while (await divideBlock.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
                var value = divideBlock.Receive(); // this should throw exception on second call
        }
        try
        {
            divideBlock.Completion.Wait();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting inconsistent results, first run:

```
Xunit.Sdk.EqualExceptionAssert.Equal() Failure 
Expected: 1000 
Actual:  127
```

then run again:

```
Xunit.Sdk.EqualExceptionAssert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 1000
Actual:   14
```

Can someone confirm that it's not "on my machine" only issue?

Gist: https://gist.github.com/plentysmart/1c2ed2e925cc3f690f61

Comment: `noOfExceptions` is not threadsafe. Try using `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: Thanks, but this code is sequential - Wait() makes sure that current task has finished.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the confusion is due to the `OutputAvailableAsync` behavior. This method will return `false` when there will never be any more output.

When a block faults (i.e., as the result of an exception from the transformation delegate), it will clear both input and output buffers. This causes `OutputAvailableAsync` to return `false`.

Comment: Yes, It looks as if `OutputAvailableAsync` sometimes returns `true` and sometimes `false` for a faulted block, just not sure if it's _by design_ or it's a bug. Have you got the same inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: No; what I see is consistent with `OutputAvailableAsync` always returning `false` once the block faults. Bear in mind that there are race conditions in the test because `TransformBlock` runs its delegate on the thread pool. So, the (small) number of exceptions you see are only when the `TransformBlock` processes the first input and produces the first output so `OAA` returns `true` but then the block faults before `Receive` is called. If the block processes both inputs then `OAA` returns `false`.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on another machine (much faster one). It's harder to reproduce but still I'm getting inconsistent results:

`Xunit.Sdk.EqualExceptionAssert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 100000
Actual:   2`

Note that I had to change max to 100000 get this.

Comment: I've updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/plentysmart/1c2ed2e925cc3f690f61). It runs much longer but I'm getting this issue every single time.